# Laravel Request::instance() returns original instance

Tags: symfony, laravel, laravel-4

I use Laravel with an API and make requests using Request::create(...) with parameters. When I use Request::instance() in my API code, I receive the original request, and not the request that I just created with the data I want to use.

Does anyone know what to do?

EDIT:

I make the call with

```
$request = Request::create('/api/v1/'.$src, strtoupper($params['method']), $params);
$content = Route::dispatch($request)->getContent();
```

$params is an associative array with the URL get parameters.

Inside the API controller I use:

```
$request = \Request::instance();
$q = (array) $request->query; // GET
```

That $q array is empty because it still uses the original request is used. I see this because when I var_dump $request->server->get("REQUEST_URI"), the original route is displayed.

Comment: How are you using them? Could you show us some code, please?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bug on Laravel. I just created a unit test and opened a pull request for the Core Team to check on it: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/5886

Comment: I see that it is closed, what should I do now?

Comment: I'm trying to catch Taylor on IRC (#laravel-dev) to understand, I'm completely lost. :)

Comment: It's not, because I don't really now how to have access to a booted Foundation/Application used to transfer that request. This is one the things I wrote in my post after his. But that was on purpose, I made it just to be a 'line of work' so they could start working on something.